# Object not recognized outside of constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to create some methods for my object but the outside of the constructor, the object isn't recognized by it's name

```
public class Playlist extends SongRecord {
    final int maxSongs = 50;

    public Playlist() {
        SongRecord[] list = new SongRecord[maxSongs];


    }
    public int size(){
        return list.length();
    }
}
```

The error message says list isn't recognized

Answer (score 2):

Because your list scope is in the constructor if u want to access list every where u need to move your list to class scope

```
  public class Playlist extends SongRecord {
  final int maxSongs = 50;
  SongRecord[] list;

  public Playlist() {
     list = new SongRecord[maxSongs];


  }
  public int size(){
     return list.length();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `list` to class scope:

```
public class Playlist extends SongRecord { 
  final int maxSongs = 50;
  private SongRecord[] list;

  public Playlist() {
    list = new SongRecord[maxSongs];
  }

  public int size(){
    return list.length();
  }
}
```